# best way of add element to list in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class ClientMatrix {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private List<ClientMatrixPriceResultGroup> matrix; //1080 elements

    @Field
    private String request;
}
```

Two operations are there.

1. ClientMatrix object insert operation
2. add one by one matrix records. 1080 elements there.then 1080 operation

to perform 2nd operation I have to read ClientMatrix first. add ClientMatrixPriceResultGroup object to list matrix. And save again.

is that the best way ?